# using generic string in VHDL report

Tags: string, generics, report, vhdl

When I use the report statement in VHDL, I want the string output to depend on a generic which I can declare at instantiation level. Can and how do I do this?
Let's say as a crazy example, in the entity I put:

```
generic ( blah : string :="happy");
```

...

then later I have in the architecture:

```
report "my mood is: " <blah> severity warning;
```

I know this doesn't work, so how do I have the generic as part of the report output?

Comment: Did you try `report ("my mood is" & blah)` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the strings using `&`:

```
report "my mood is " & blah severity warning;
```